# why isn't my simple string being constructed correctly?

Tags: c++, string

I have a simple function that builds a string representation of a simple 'Movie' object.  I'm doing this ...

```
string Movie::getDisplayText() {
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << "Title: " << this->getTitle() << "\tYear: "+this->getYear() << "\tGenre: " << this->getGenre();
  string ret = oss.str();

  return ret;
}
```

But the string that gets built and returned looks like this ...

```
\�tle: Star Wars�B
    Genre: Science-Fiction
```

When I add this line to test the values are valid ...

```
cout << "DEBUG Title: " << this->getTitle() << "\tYear: "+this->getYear() << "\tGenre: " << this->getGenre() << "\n" << endl;
```

... it outputs to 'cout' a correct looking string so I know the values are all initialized correctly ...

```
DEBUG title='Star Wars'; year='1977'; genre='Science-Fiction';
```

What's wrong with my ostringstream code?

Comment: Adding integers to string literals doesn't do concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
string Movie::getDisplayText() {
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << "Title: " << this->getTitle() << "\tYear: "+this->getYear() << "\tGenre: " << this->getGenre();
  string ret = oss.str();

  return ret;
}
```

It should be

```
string Movie::getDisplayText() {
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << "Title: " << this->getTitle() << "\tYear: " << this->getYear() << "\tGenre: " << this->getGenre();
  string ret = oss.str();

  return ret;
}
```

Not the difference after the \tYear:. The reason is that adding a string literal and an int together does not result in concatenation.

Comment: ARRRGGH!!!  Can't believe I missed that, thanks for being a fresh pair of eyes for me.